# UILabel not updating in Swift3 when passed variable from other Controller via delegate

Tags: ios, swift

I have passed a variable from LoginViewController to ViewController via a delegate.  As far as I am aware (via a print debug) the variable has been passed ok.  I now want it to update the UIlabel.

LoginViewController

```
//
//  LoginViewController.swift
//  KeepScore
//
//  Created by Rich Downs on 28/09/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Rich Downs. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

protocol UsernameSentDelegate {
func userLoggedIn(data: String)
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: UsernameSentDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var displayUserName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    if (userPassword!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty) { return; }

// send user data to server side


    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/userLogin.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

               // spinningActivity!.hide(true)


               if(error != nil)
                {

                    //Display an alert message
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]


                    // retrieve username and pass it to View Controller screen through delegate
                    let username = (json!["user_name"])
                    if self.delegate != nil {
                        let usernameData = username
                        self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: usernameData as! String)

                   }

                    // retrieve login details and check to see if all ok

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                        //print(returnValue);
                        if(returnValue != "error")
                        {
                             UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

                            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

                            let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage!)
                            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                            appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav


                        } else {
                            // display an alert message
                            let userMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    }
                } catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }


        }



    }

    task.resume()


}




}
```

And ViewController - which is my main page when a user is logged in.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  KeepScore
//
//  Created by Rich Downs on 28/09/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Rich Downs. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UsernameSentDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var receiveUsername: UILabel!

//recieves username from delegate from LoginViewController
func userLoggedIn(data: String) {


    self.receiveUsername.text = data //sets label.text to new data
    print (self.receiveUsername.text)  //prints a check to see if worked (Samuel Bawdry)
    //self.receiveUsername.setNeedsDisplay() //update label in view
        self.receiveUsername.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print (receiveUsername.text) //print original label.text (Label)
//   receiveUsername = self
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let loginViewController: LoginViewController = segue.destination as! LoginViewController
        loginViewController.delegate = self
    }
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{

   let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.bool(UserDefaults.standard)(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");

    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);
    }

}


@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self);

}


}
```

The ViewController var receiveUsername.text prints out in the Debug area the correct String.  So to my knowledge it is being passed correctly between controllers.  The issue is that it is not updating the UILabel with the new value.

App Delegate script which detects whether the user is already logged in and if so goes straight to View Controller, if not goes straight to Login View Controller:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
```

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.bool(UserDefaults.standard)(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

    if(!isUserLoggedIn)
    {

        let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")

        self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {

        let protectedPage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

        self.window?.rootViewController = protectedPage
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
```

Comment: Just to debug, have you tried setting the receiveUsername.text to an arbitrary string or setting the text outside the DispatchQueue? Just trying to get some context.

Comment: I have tried setting it outside the dispatch queue - no luck.  I believe i did try setting it to an arbitrary string (though I'm not 100% what this is!) -> as mentioned - it prints the correct new string in the debug window - just not updating, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Have you linked correctly the IBOutlet, or made sure you have only one UILabel linked to this property?

Comment: - yes, there are only 2 labels on the View. "Welcome, " and "Label".  "Label" is IBOutlet you see on the 2nd section of the code above

Comment: Can you set something like `self.receiveUsername.backgroundColor = UIColor.red()` to make sure you're seeing the right one?

Comment: I added the line: self.receiveUsername.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

as the last line in the dispatch, but it had no effect on anything...

Comment: Show the code where you're setting the delegate.  Are you sure the instance in the delegate is the same instance that is on screen?

Comment: import UIKit

protocol UsernameSentDelegate {
    func userLoggedIn(data: String)
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: UsernameSentDelegate? = nil
    
    IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
    IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    IBOutlet weak var displayUserName: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

(i had to remove the at symbols)

Comment: @dan he said that his `print(self.receiveUsername.text)` returns the correct string, so the delegate is not the issue

Comment: @RichardDowns Add the code as an edit to your question, not in a comment.  Also, that isn't the code we need.  Show the code where you are actually setting the delegate to something.  You should have a `loginViewController.delegate = something` somewhere that is likely the cause of your issue.

Comment: I think I originally had `loginViewController.delegate =...` but it errored.  It only accepted the delegate when i put .self in front of it

Comment: That still isn't the code I care about.  Your delegate isn't nil, so somewhere in your app there has to be a place where you are doing `self.delegate = ...` or `delegate = ...` or `x.delegate = ...`.  Find and post that code.

Comment: I only have 2 scripts, ViewController and LoginViewController that deal with this (it's literally just a user registration and login).  I will edit and post both scripts in full

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in an async block and remove `self.receiveUsername.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: I've tried that.  

When I do it this way (with the follow code also applied):
     
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print (receiveUsername.text) //print original label.text (Label)
    //   receiveUsername = self
    }

in the debug area it prints the name "Samuel Bawdry" but then prints "label"

Only when i run it inside the async block is "Samuel Bawdry" outputted last.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does viewDidLoad have to do with any of this? You didn't mention it anywhere in your original question.

Comment: Sorry I was just showing where the other print command is for debugging purposes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that instead of dismissing your login view controller and going back to your previous controller you are creating an entirely new controller stack and replacing your old ones.

Replace these lines:

```
let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")

let mainPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainPage!)
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = mainPageNav
```

With code that just dismisses your current view controller:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or if you are pushing your login view controller onto a navigation controller instead of presenting it modally:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: This just about fixes it.  Now when I log in it show the correct String for the label  'Welcome, Samuel Bawdry'

However, if I restart the app while logged in so that when the app boots up it goes straight into the 'already logged in view (ViewController) the string returns to 'label' rather than 'Samuel Bawdry' - I have to log out and log back in.  I have updated the above code to show the app delegate script which deals with whether a user is logged in or not upon the app loading.